# Use C++ macro string concatenation to access object properties

Tags: c++

I have some code which looks like this. `State` is meant to be a container around some data, and is meant to call some variable callbacks, stored separately in the `Callbacks` struct. Here, `State` only has 2 variables, but it has more in practice.

```
#include <functional>
#include <array>

struct Callbacks {
    using Callback = std::function<void()>;

    Callback x = nullptr;
    Callback y = nullptr;
};

struct State {
private:
    std::array<int, 2> data_;

public:
    auto& x() { return data_[0]; }
    auto& y() { return data_[1]; }

    auto x() const { return data_[0]; }
    auto y() const { return data_[1]; }

    void x(int value, const Callbacks& cbs) {
        x() = value;
        if (cbs.x != nullptr) {
            cbs.x();
        }
    }

    void y(int value, const Callbacks& cbs) {
        y() = value;
        if (cbs.y !=  nullptr) {
            cbs.y();
        }
    }
};
```

The code for the accessors is quite redundant, and copy-pasting becomes error prone when adding tens of variables for state. I'd like to simplify this with a preprocessor macro. This is what I've tried:

```
#define ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(name, location) \
    auto& name() { return location; } \
    auto name() const { return location; } \
    void name(int value, const Callbacks& cbs) { \
        name() = value; \
        if (cbs.##name != nullptr) { \
            cbs.##name(value); \
        } \
    }

struct State2 {
private:
    std::array<int, 2> data_;

public:
    ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(x, data_[0]);
    ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(y, data_[1]);
};
```

However, I'm having some trouble getting the `cbs.##name` portion to compile, which is meant to use the name of the variable to access one of the callbacks. I'm not sure if I'm simply misusing the macro syntax, or if my understanding of the macro concatenation is incorrect, or if what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible.

These are the errors I get with Clang 8 on Linux. It seems that only the period is being concatenated to create a token, rather than `cbs.` as I'd like, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
/tmp/test.cpp:53:2: error: pasting formed '.x', an invalid preprocessing token
        ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(x, data_[0]);
        ^
/tmp/test.cpp:43:11: note: expanded from macro 'ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS'
                if (cbs.##name != nullptr) { \
                        ^
/tmp/test.cpp:53:2: error: pasting formed '.x', an invalid preprocessing token
/tmp/test.cpp:44:8: note: expanded from macro 'ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS'
                        cbs.##name(value); \
                            ^
/tmp/test.cpp:54:2: error: pasting formed '.y', an invalid preprocessing token
        ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(y, data_[1]);
        ^
/tmp/test.cpp:43:11: note: expanded from macro 'ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS'
                if (cbs.##name != nullptr) { \
                        ^
/tmp/test.cpp:54:2: error: pasting formed '.y', an invalid preprocessing token
/tmp/test.cpp:44:8: note: expanded from macro 'ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS'
                        cbs.##name(value); \
                            ^
/tmp/test.cpp:53:2: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const Callbacks::Callback' (aka 'const function<void ()>')
        ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(x, data_[0]);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:44:4: note: expanded from macro 'ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS'
                        cbs.##name(value); \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:577:12: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
      _Res operator()(_ArgTypes... __args) const;
           ^
/tmp/test.cpp:54:2: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const Callbacks::Callback' (aka 'const function<void ()>')
        ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(y, data_[1]);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:44:4: note: expanded from macro 'ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS'
                        cbs.##name(value); \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:577:12: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
      _Res operator()(_ArgTypes... __args) const;
           ^
6 errors generated.
```

Comment: Removing `##` should fix it.

Comment: Accessors exist for a reason, they are part of your design and you should either make your members public (if you do not wish to control access to them) or write them out in full (if accessors are part of your program design). Using the preprocessor for something like this is (in my opinion) a _terrible_ idea and _will_ result in less readable code and quite possibly hard to track down bugs. Just a friendly warning :p

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 In principle I do agree, but OP is writing accessors for elements in an array. Even with the array being public the accessors would be justified. Also the accessors return a non-const reference (which breaks any encapsulation), hence the array elements can be considered public already

Comment: Which is why they should not be behind accessors if possible (i.e not maintaining a API which uses accessors only) or manually defined to show to the reader that they are meant to be public and trivial.

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 not sure if you got my point. It is a common pattern to provide `x`, `y` (and `z`) accessors for array elements, so that users of the class dont have to mess around with the array directly. In that case having accessors that do nothing but access the array elements is just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two fixes (Verified by generating preprocessor output)

1. Remove `##` from `cbs.##name`
2. `cbs.##name(value)` Callback doesn't take `value` as parameter.

```
#define ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(name, location) \
    auto& name() { return location; } \
    auto name() const { return location; } \
    void name(int value, const Callbacks& cbs) { \
        name() = value; \
        if (cbs.name != nullptr) { \
            cbs.name(); \
        } \
    }

struct State2 {
private:
    std::array<int, 2> data_;

public:
    ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(x, data_[0]);
    ACCESSOR_WITH_CALLBACKS(y, data_[1]);
};
```